# How write datatype in file with julia

Tags: julia

In julia, I would like write in a file a variable and his type in order to reuse it later. Like this:

```
var = Float64(15)
stream = open("foo.dat", "w")
write(stream, typeof(var))
write(stream, var)
close(stream)

stream = open("foo.dat", "r")
typevar = read(stream, DataType)
var = read(stream, typevar)
close(stream)
```

The third line doesn't work :

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: `write` has no method matching write(::IOStream, ::Type{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
write(::IO, ::Any)
```

How can I do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Have you looked into the JLD package?  You can use that to store complete Julia objects, which will include their types.

Comment: Also, depending on what you want, that might not even be necessary.  For instance, if you just have an Array of say `Float64` objects, then you could just use `writedlm` to write it to a .txt file and then `readdlm` to read it back in.  `readdlm` will take an optional argument to specify the type when reading the data back in.

Comment: Thank you Michael :) I look JLD and HDF5 packages. writedlm write text, but I would to write binary.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain of this, but I don't know of a way to write a file type to a canonical binary file - I suspect that there might not be a way, since file types differ across languages, but I could easily be wrong.  As a work-around, however, you could just write one extra number or character at the beginning of your file that represents a file type and then keep a dictionary that maps those on to file types.  A bit of a hack, but it would probably do the trick.

Comment: I could not run JDL. HDF5 works well, but I don't understand how it encodes the file.

Comment: JLD is the correct solution. What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Since there doesn't seem to be any strong requirements about the format of your file, using the JLD package is the best way, as many commenters have said above. It will automatically track the types of everything you store in it, and so you can read the values back directly.

You will have to install the package with `Pkg.add("JLD")` . Having done that, using it is simple:

```
julia> using JLD
INFO: Precompiling module JLD...
INFO: Recompiling stale cache file /Users/aviks/.julia/lib/v0.4/FileIO.ji for module FileIO.

julia> a=10
10

julia> b="A String"
"A String"

julia> c=[1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> file = jldopen("/tmp/mydata.jld", "w")
Julia data file version 0.1.1: /tmp/mydata.jld

julia> write(file, "a", a)

julia> write(file, "b", b)

julia> write(file, "c", c)

julia> close(file)
```

Then, when you want to read the variables, in new REPL session

```
julia> using JLD

julia> d=load("/tmp/mydata.jld")
Dict{ByteString,Any} with 3 entries:
  "c" => [1,2]
  "b" => "A String"
  "a" => 10

julia> d["a"]
10

julia> d["b"]
"A String"

julia> d["c"]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
```

More information about the JLD package is available at: https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl

Answer (score 0):

My best way :

```
var = Float64(89)
typevar = string(typeof(var), "\n")

s = open("var.dat", "w")
write(s, typevar, var) # Float64\n@V@
close(s)

s = open("var.dat", "r")
typevar = chomp(readline(s)) # delete "\n"
var = read(s, eval(parse(typevar)))
close(s)
```